# c# multiforms DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

On the first form I have:

```
var dsUni = new DataSet();
dsUni.ReadXml(pathDesc);
frm02.dgv02.DataSource = dsUni.Tables[0];
frm02.ShowDialog();
dsUni.WriteXml(pathDesc); //this line is in the frm02.ClosingEvent
```

So, on the secondForm I need the same DataSet(dsUni) to writeXml from changed dgv02.
But, i got the errors:
The name 'dsUni' does not exist in the current context
Please, give me a solution for this case.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact error that you get, and which line causes it.

Comment: I edited the post. Error is: The name 'dsUni' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It wont work that way ! how about passing it as a parameter on the constructer of the 2nd form ?

Comment: Thankyou Hichem, but your "help" is without help. I did not ask the question to see what you all know.

Comment: Then why did you ask? Surely what we know is what will help answer the question? There are better ways to get people to help you!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the second form doesn't have a variable named `dsUni` defined. You need to define it, such as `var dsUni = new DataSet();` did on the first form. While you have passed the data itself along via the line `frm02.dgv02.DataSource = dsUni.Tables[0];`, the variable named `dsUni` is local to form1, so form2 doesn't know about it. If you want to access that dataset under the name `dsUni`, you must expose it so form2 can directly access it, or create a new local variable by that name on form2 and load it with your desired data (very inefficent, unless you just use a pointer back to form1's dsUni).

If you create a new variable on form2 called `dsUni`, don't forget to load it with your desired data, as it will start out empty.

Comment: But, StarPilot, I allready defined dsUni on the firstForm. I allready filled that dsUni by the data from xmlFile. If I define that dsUni on the secondForm again - it wil be new and Empty. I tried and it wrote empty xmlFile. Or, must I maybe again create DataSet and again readXml on the second form. I allready did all that on the firstForm ?

Comment: @Bonaca. You could add a property of type dataset to form2, then after you've created it in form1 assign it, but it's a really, really bad option. Start down that route and before you know it you have to have all your UI instanced before can sniff in the general direction of the user.

Comment: @Bonaca, the problem is that you defined `dsUni` as a local on form1. form2 cannot see it. You have to expose it to form2 in some fashion if you want form2 to access it. You can do that many ways. Some are good, some are hacks. But if you want to use that loaded dataset over in form2, you got to pass the data somehow. One of the simplest ways, for example, is you define a new method on form2 which takes a pointer to the dataset, and have form 2 store that pointer in a private class level variable, so form 2 can do whatever it needs with the dataset. Not the most graceful method, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this it's just asking for it.

Huge amount of technical debt justwaiting to happen.

There's a few ways to do it better, but this one you can build on.

Create a little class e.g.

```
public class MyData()
{
   public Dataset MyDataset {get; private set;}

   // add constructor and all methods related to the dataset here. 
}
```

Then just create one in Form1, do what you have to do and pass it to form2, either as a property or in the constructor.

If it's common and it's not totally trivial, create a common something, put all the methods that relate to it in there and then use it. As soon as you start with the form2 depends on form1 manouevre you might as conserve energy and just jam a biro up your left nostril as hard as you can, the headache will be similar.

An interface will be better, but that's the next lesson.